# How to get "deleted" Outlook Calendar Events

Tags: python-o365

I am using O365 for automated calendar events processing and trying to find a way to list "deleted" events.

According to this [text](https://stackoverflow.com) deleted events are availabe for 14 day.

However I cannot find the proper way to code this in O365. Am I overlooking something or is this just not implemented?

outlook_calendar = self.account.schedule().get_calendar(calendar_id=calendar_id)
query = (outlook_calendar.new_query("start").greater_equal(start_dt).chain("and")
.on_attribute("end").less_equal(end_dt)
query_result = outlook_calendar.get_events(query=query, limit=None, include_recurring=False)
calendar_events = list(query_result)

`